# What should I put as the "subject" in an email request for masters research interviews?

Tags: email, interview

I have to send emails to make an appointment with people to interview them for my Master's research. What would be the best "subject" to put in the email to get their attention and get a response?

Comment: What do you mean by "object"? Subject? Or something else? Please explain.

Comment: Sorry my first language is french we say "objet" . I think we say subject in english i will correct it. Thank you